# Time Complexity of removing the last element from a static array- O(n) or O(1)?

Tags: arrays, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of removing an exact last element from the static array? Is it O(n) or O(1)? Because last element can easily be accessed within O(1) and elements need not be shifted leftwards. But I know that the size of the array changes now. But cant leave the last element empty in the array instead of creating a new array with size one less than earlier and copy all the remaining elements which takes O(n) complexity? Isn't it possible to have empty element/free memory space in an array by deleting the last element? Then time complexity for this operation will only be O(1). Is my intuition correct?

Comment: By definition static arrays are static, you cannot add or remove elements. So your question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Also there's no such thing as leaving an element in an array 'empty'. A memory address always has some value, and zero is not the same as no value.

Comment: @Nick, since the question mentions no language, we should probably at least allow for the *possibility* of a usable "empty" value (such as Python's `None`).

Answer (score 0):

If you have to create a *new* array with one less element and copy into it, that would be `O(n)`. However, most people would simply have an array of the maximum required size and store the number of elements in use separately<sup>(1)</sup>.

With that sort of scheme, deletion at the end is very much `O(1)`.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Or, as you posit, some special *value* that is distinguishable from all other values, such as `None` in Python, or `-1` in a C-like language where you're only storing non-negative integers into the collection.